# All links and formatting lost when copying text from Pages to another text editor

Tags: pages, copy-paste

Steps to reproduce:

1. open a blank document in Pages
2. write some text
3. turn one of the words into a hyperlink and make one of the words bold
4. copy all text and paste it into another word processor (e.g., Google Docs)

What happened:

The link and formatting is lost. Only the pure text is pasted.

What should have happened:

The rich text should have been pasted.

Comment: Does the same happen if you paste it into TextEdit?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, the issue does not occur when pasting into TextEdit. It pastes all the links and bold/italic text normally. Could it be that Apple has a proprietary rich text clipboard format that other non-Apple editors don’t understand?

Comment: I can't test on Google Docs, but this is what I get in Word & TextEdit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n26G.png - neither is perfect, & Word loses the font, but both retain the link info, still clickable. I'm inclined to think it's a Google issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin It looks like you’re copying from a website in the browser. That’s not what my problem is about.

Comment: Same difference - Pages/browser. The issue isn't where it's from, it's where you're pasting **to** which doesn't conform properly. Unsurprisingly, as you're talking about Google & they wilfully ignore Mac Toolbox standards in many things. If you want things to 'just work as expected' you have to avoid Google products.

Comment: @Tetsujin My problem is actually that copy-pasting rich text doesn’t work from Pages to the editor on Patreon’s website. I used to write my articles in Google Docs and copy-paste them to Patreon. I wanted to switch to Pages, but when I write an article in Pages and copy-paste it to Patreon, all the links and formatting is lost. So right now, I have to continue using Google Docs. From my perspective, the problem is with Pages.